# Css arrow(with border) not working in input type button

Tags: html, css

So, the code goes like this:

**HTML**:

```
<input type="button" id="oneid" class="cls">
```

**CSS**

```
.cls {
border: none;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
height: 200px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
display: block;
width: 500px;
position: absolute;
cursor: pointer;
}
.cls:before {
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
display: block;
content: "";
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
border-right:16px solid #000000;
border-top:16px solid #000000;
transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

I got two questions:

1) Why can't I make the `:before` arrow show up with `input` tag, while with `span` tag instead of `input` the arrow is showing? How to make this with `input` tag?

`<input type="button" id="oneid" class="cls">` -- NOT working example.

`<span type="button" id="oneid" class="cls"></span>` -- WORKING example.

2) How to center the `:before` arrow correctly? Because `top` and `left` set for `50%` not really center the arrow in the middle.

*I want a cross-browser solution and with css and html only.

Comment: You can't use :before or :after on input element, use <button> instead.

Comment: Oh... got it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:-

```
<button type="submit" id="oneid" class="cls">button</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. Worth to mention the reason tho -- 

> You can't use :before or :after on input element